# Symfony FOSUserBundle can't set encoder

Tags: symfony, encoding, fosuserbundle

I can not set an encoding for my pwd, only the mode 'plaintext' works. I use the FOSUser bundle:

security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        GestionBundle\Entity\Acteur: plaintext

    providers:
        main_provider:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        [...]

        main:
            pattern: ^/           
            anonymous: false    
            provider: main_provider
            form_login: 
                login_path:          fos_user_security_login   
                check_path:          fos_user_security_check      
                default_target_path: route_accueil               
            logout:
                path:   fos_user_security_logout    
                target: /login
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm                
    firewall_name: main             
    user_class:    GestionBundle\Entity\Acteur
```

My classes:

```
abstract class Acteur extends FOS\UserBundle\Model\User { ... }

abstract class Utilisateur extends Acteur { ... }

class Professionnel extends Utilisateur { ... }
class Beneficiaire extends Utilisateur { ... }
```

Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

In `security.yml`, set encryption for FOSUserBundle instead to your overwritten `Acteur` entity :

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
```

Hence you declare only extra properties you need in your `Acteur` Entity. Common properties like `username`, `email`, `password` are already declared in `FOSUserBundle\Model\User`.

While creating a new user.

- Set `plainPassword`(without encryption)
- Set salt to the user entity (will be used for encryption)
- Fill up any additional property like `name`, `email` etc.

Then call `FOSUserBundle` `UserManager` service to do the rest :

```
$user; // fill up any value like name etc with plainPassword.
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

The encryption will be taken care automatically.

Note : If your are accepting `password` from any Register `FormType` or so, You can expose `plainPassword` property to the form.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but the password is not encrypted in database :

```
$professionnel1 = new Professionnel();
[...]
$professionnel1->setPassword("admin");
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$userManager->updateUser($professionnel1);
```

security.yml :

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```